# ZF2, create dynamic menu at module initiation

Tags: events, navigation, url-routing, zend-framework2

I have a menu which I need to create dynamically (some blog pages are added from a database). [ZF2 Dynamic Menu with Zend\Navigation\Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531423/zf2-dynamic-menu-with-zend-navigation-navigation) addresses how to do this for an individual controller/action.

But how should this be done for all requests, at the moment of initialising the module?

I need at least the routeMatch object (to get the language parameter) and I have seen the below to get that:

```
    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e) 
    { 
        $app = $e->getApplication(); 
        $em  = $app->getEventManager(); 

        $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) { 
            $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
        }); 
    }
```

But in the docs it says:

"the onBootstrap() method is called for every module implementing this feature, on every page request, and should only be used for performing lightweight tasks such as registering event listeners."

What would be the best place and way to initialise dynamic navigation (or other more complicated logic) in Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 1):

The correct place is indeed bootstrap to do this sort of things. Bear in mind the code at bootstrap is run at every request, so make it as lightweight as possible. If you want to inject navigation, try to cache the navigation structure from your database and inject the version from cache.

This behaviour is something I did in [ensemble](http://ensemble.github.com). It fetches data from the database to build routes dynamically and based on the routes, the navigation structure is build. The routes and navigation are injected in respectively the router and navigation container, so at dispatch of the application is seems there is nothing different from a "normal" request with routes configured in the module.config.php.

For some examples you should check out the [kernel](https://github.com/ensemble/EnsembleKernel), currently only availble with a Doctrine adapter (Zend\Db coming soon). It registers listeners to hook up early, it parses the database results into a route and navigation structure and those can be cached to increase performance.

If you need more specific information, please update your question to ask more about what you miss in the bigger picture.